# How can I decode a mobile encoded file?

Tags: encryption

I am using filelock software in my Android phone. You can encode (encrypt) any file in this software by a password. I forgot my password and without password I cant decode my file. Is there any solution that I can decode my files without knowing the password?

Comment: In short: That's the idea behind encryption. You don't know the key, you don't see the content. There might be a possibility using "brute force", but that can take hours at best and years at worst for a single file only to be processed (of course, after the first file you'd know the password then). // Maybe you [edit] your question and add some more details, e.g. what encryption software you used (including a link to it). Then someone with more experience like me might be able to give a better answer.

Comment: It wouldn't be a good encryption software if you could decode without a password.